# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor de la misma posición de 2 arrays distintos en C?

Tags: array, c

Llevo ya unas horas atascado en una parte de un ejercicio que no consigo averiguar como resolverlo. Resulta que tengo 2 arras distintos, uno con el abecedario y el otro el abecedario al revés. Hasta ahora la persona introduce un código y dentro de un array busca ese carácter de forma recursiva, pero lo que quiero es que una vez obtenida ese carácter, me muestre la letra que está en la misma posición del otro array, no sé si me he explicado bien. Agradecería vuestra ayuda, gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr5zb.png)

```
introducir el código void busqueda(char cript[], int tam, int valorbusq){
for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
    if(valorbusq == cript[i])
    {
        return i;
    }
}

return -1;
```

}

int main(){
    char alfab[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char cripto[] = {'z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'};
    char codigo;

```
cout << "Introduce el mensaje oculto: " << endl;
cin >> codigo;

char mensaje = busqueda(cripto, 26, codigo);

if(mensaje >= 0)
{
    cout << "El mensaje ha sido descifrado." << endl;
}else{
    cout << "Mensaje no se puede descifrar." << endl;
}
```

}

Esto es el código que tengo por ahora, no sé si voy bien encaminado o no, gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el mismo indice para ambos. Supongamos que estás recorriendo tu arreglo con un for.
Al final de cada iteración la variable temporal (generalmente llamada i) incrementara en 1.

Si Array Abecedario = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ....] tenemos que:

La primera vez i valdrá 0 entonces Abecedario[0] (eso es abecedario en la posicion 0) valdrá a. i se incrementará en + 1 y pasará a la siguiente iteración.

La segunda vez, como se incrementó i, está valdrá 1. Abecedario[1] (en la posición 1) valdrá b.

Así sucesivamente deberias recorrer el arreglo. O por lo menos debes llevar un contador que sirva de indice. Lo unico que tienes que hacer es usar el mismo indice para ambos arreglos.

Tiendo abecedario = [a, b, c ...] y abecedarioInvertido = [z, y, x ...] el llamado sería algo asi:

abecedario[i] y abecedarioInvertido[i]

Espero que mí respuesta te sea de utilidad. Cualquier cosa que no haya quedado clara, por favor comentalo. Con mucho gusto intentaré hacerme entender de mejor manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, me imaginaba que sería algo así, lo único que no sé exactamente como usar contadores.